# Proper Edit And Update Method In RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the update method doesn't update the record, it creates a new one.

how can I change the code to do the proper job?

here the controller bit:

```
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

the edit view:

```
= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f|

%p
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title

%p
    = f.label :content
    = f.text_area :content

%p
    = f.submit
```

Comment: Please post your `post_params` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form tag:

`= form_for @post do |f|`

It isn't using the variable you set up in your controller so it doesn't know it isn't a new object.

You also shouldn't need to specify the url, so long as you have the resource defined in your routes file.

Comment: I also added @post = Post.find(params[:id]) to the update method ! now everything works just fine!